# Is it possible to implement a method that takes a format string?

Tags: rust

I've found myself using `.expect("...")` to panic with an helpful error message in a lot of places where I don't care about recovering from an error. Example:

```
let p = "foo.txt";
let f = File::open(p).expect("File not found");
```

However, I would like to print more information by using a formatted string. This is what I could do:

```
let f = File::open(p).expect(&format("{} not found", p));
```

This has two problems:

1. The `format` call will be evaluated eagerly.
2. It's unnecessarily verbose.

Ideally, I would like to write:

```
// pseudocode
let f = File::open(p).expect_fmt("{} not found", p);
```

But I suppose that's not possible without variadic generic functions and compile-time parsing of strings.

The only alternative I've found is the following:

```
let f = File::open(p).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("{} not found", p));
```

Which is still a little bit too verbose for my taste.

It's acceptable if the answer uses nightly Rust.

Comment: Why do not you use a macro?

Comment: @Boiethios, I could, but then I would lose the method-like chaining syntax... correct?

Comment: No, you create a macro `.expect_fmt("...", ...)` that expands to `expect(&format("...", ...))`

Comment: @Boiethios: I'm still a Rust beginner - I assumed that macros could not be used with method-like syntax *(i.e. you have to write something like `expect_fmt!(File::open(p), "{} not found", p)`... If I'm wrong, I'd love to see your answer

Comment: Maybe you are right. It seems you cannot chain with a macro.

Comment: This was already proposed in the past: [RFC 1952](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1952), but the answer to it was basically `unwrap_or_else`.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.
;)

Comment: @hellow: I know.

Comment: I was sure, that you know, but you opened a bounty and have two answers which you haven't commented yet. Either accept one of them and give the bounty to the user or clarify why the answer doesn't suit you.

Comment: @hellow: the bounty ends tomorrow. I will select an answer before then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: No.

---

While there's not much to be done about reducing your verbosity issues, you can avoid the memory allocation by using [`std::fmt::Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html)

```
trait ResultExt<T, E> {
    fn expect_fmt<D>(self, msg: D) -> T
    where
        D: std::fmt::Display;
}

impl<T, E> ResultExt<T, E> for Result<T, E>
where
    E: std::error::Error,
{
    fn expect_fmt<D>(self, msg: D) -> T
    where
        D: std::fmt::Display,
    {
        match self {
            Ok(t) => t,
            Err(e) => panic!("{}: {}", msg, e),
        }
    }
}

use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let p = "foo.txt";
    let f = File::open(p).expect_fmt(format_args!("{} not found", p));
}
```

Feel free to adjust the trait bounds as you see fit.

> not possible without variadic generic functions and **compile-time parsing of strings**

That's exactly what the `format_args` macro does, but you still have to call it.

Answer (score 6):

For avoiding eagerly formatting of the error message a closure may be used, toghether with a simple macro for reducing verbosity a little bit:

```
macro_rules! crash {
    ( $( $p:tt ),* ) => {
        |_| panic!($($p),*);
    };
}
```

then the statement sugarizes as:

```
    let f = File::open(p).unwrap_or_else(crash!("{} not found", p));
```

No much added value with this approach.

Have you considered [error-chain](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/error-chain) or [failure](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/failure) as alternatives for your error management design?

They have a lot to offer for effective error handling.

Using a simple macro, you should anyway tweak *creatively* the syntax to get near your desiderata, below an `error-chain` based example:

```
macro_rules! or {
    ( $( $p:tt ),* ) => {{
        || format!($($p),*)
    }};
}

fn run() -> Result<()> {
    use std::fs::File;
    // This operation will fail
    let p = "foo";

    File::open(p).chain_err(or!("unable to open {} file", p))?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Read as: invoke `chain_error` method with a variadic arg list.